# weird html rendering issue with react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to render the message with html tags inside it. The rendering is working fine if the string is passed as prop, but when the same is passed from a variable the display text has encoded text.

Any idea how do I get it working in both scenarios.?

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.name)
    return <div>{this.props.name}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="&lt;p&gt;How are you?&lt;/p&gt;" />,
  document.getElementById('container') --> **<p>How are you?</p>** 
);


class HelloOther extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const name = "&lt;p&gt;How are you?&lt;/p&gt;" 
    return <Hello name={name} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloOther />,
  document.getElementById('container2') -- &lt;p&gt;How are you?&lt;/p&gt; -- > why?
);
```

Fiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/d6s7be1f/2/

Comment: This is a feature of React. HTML is automatically escaped to prevent [injection attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/Injection_Flaws). Do you want the HTML output of the first scenario, or do you actually want to display HTML from a variable or a trusted external source?

Comment: I want the output of first scenario. just to display the text with tags

Comment: I'm curious as to why this is different.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  createMarkup() {
    return {__html: this.props.name};
  }
  render() {
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup()} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we achieve this without dangerouslySetInnerHTML like how we could do in the first example.

Comment: I have no any solutions of this problem

Answer (score 2):

From [React Docs:](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

> In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to
> inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS)
> attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type
> out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html key, to
> remind yourself that it’s dangerous.

Unless you want to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, you could use a regex to wrap the string with html tags. This way, you don't have to pass html entities in the string. You just pass the string and wrap the string with html tag using `.replace()` function.

Since you also want the string to be parsed as HTML, you could pass an extra prop to the `Hello` component that is then used to wrap the string with the desired html tag and also render the string nested within the desired html tag

```js
function HTMLTag({ tag, children }) {
  return React.createElement(tag, null, children);
}

class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { name, tag } = this.props;
    const str = name.replace(/(.+)/, `<${tag}>$1</${tag}>`);
    return ( 
        <div>
        <HTMLTag tag={tag}>{str}</HTMLTag>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

class HelloOther extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const name = "How are you?"; 
    return <Hello name={name} tag="h3" />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="How are you?" tag="p" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloOther />,
  document.getElementById('container2')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<div id="container2"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help. Is there a way we could achieve the similar to first approach

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by _similar to first approach_?